# Cruise Control is not showing modifications

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol

our Cruise Control is not displaying the modifications correctly. 
It looks like it can't retrieve the information. I havent been able to figure out why.

[image: screenshot]

[edit] I have found something, that looks fishy:

In the JMX Console, in every project the datatype of `commitMessages` is 
`[[Ljava.lang.String` and `getBuildOutput` is `[Ljava.lang.String`
Yes, including the bracket(s) and the "L".

[image]

If I click on Invoke I get `[[Ljava.lang.String;@f6dd4` instead of the contents.

Aint that a bug in CC?

Comment: What do the CCNet logs say? You might need to crank up the verbosity first though.

Comment: we have CC, not CCNet anyways, I set the logging level to DEBUG. I'll post my findings here (if there are any). thx!